# How do I interpret the chemical potential for hydrogen atoms in a neutral gas of hydrogen, protons and electrons?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

I am currently self-studying the lecture notes of David Tong on Statistical Physics. In question 6 of problem sheet 2 (https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/omg2.pdf) we are asked to find a formula for the proportion of particles in the gas given an equilibrium condition $\mu_H = \mu_e + \mu_p$. Now, I have got the required answer by treating the hydrogen gas in the grand canonical ensemble and setting the chemical potential equal to $\mu = \mu_H - \Delta$ (with $-\Delta$ being the binding energy of hydrogen). What I don't understand is why the $-\Delta$ must be added to the chemical potential. I understand that an extra hydrogen atom will mean the gas loses energy $\Delta$ since an electron and proton must bind. However, my understanding is that this would already be taken into account in $\mu_H$ without the need to subtract $\Delta$. So my question is: What is the interpretation of $\mu_H$ in this case if it is not accounting for the change in potential $\Delta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chemical potential is defined as $\mu=u-Ts+Pv$ where $u(s)(v)$ are internal energy(entropy)(volume) per particle. Now for the calculation of the $\mu_e$ and $\mu_p$, you used the formula for an ideal gas $u_{ideal}-Ts_{ideal}$. When you use the same formula for hydrogen atoms, you must note that the internal energy of each hydrogen atom is $\Delta$ lower than that of the ideal gas(which is just the kinetic energy), i.e. $H_H=\frac{p_h^2}{2m_H}-\Delta$ hence $u_H=u_{ideal}-\Delta$. The calculation of entropy will not change in any way, so the chemical potential of hydrogen is $u_{ideal}-\Delta-Ts+Pv$. The quantity $u_{ideal}-Ts+Pv$ is what you would have calculated using the grand canonical ensemble, and so you have  $\mu=\mu_H-\Delta$. Hope this helps

Comment: Aha! This makes sense! So, since we treat the electron and proton gases as ideal we are setting the zero of potential energy at $\Delta = 13.6\,$eV _above_ the potential energy of the hydrogen gas. So we could equally _add_ a factor of $\Delta$ to the Hamiltonian for electrons and protons and get the same result by treating the _hydrogen_ gas as ideal. Cheers!